# How to make bars in ggplot2 barplot interactive in shiny?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I'm plotting a barplot in ggplot2 in a shiny application.

[image]

What I would like is that when the mouse hovers over one of the bars, the bar becomes highlighted (maybe by a stronger outline) and when I click (or doubleclick) the bar, the corresponding x-value becomes available to be used as input for a `textOutput`.

I tried to find examples on the shiny documentation, but there it's mostly about returning x-, y-values from the pointer location. Is there an example I could use as a starting point?

Comment: Do you want `ggplot2` solutions only? if not, you can also look at [rcharts](http://ramnathv.github.io/rCharts/)

Comment: would be nice to use ggplot2 because i'm more familiar with it at the moment.

Comment: take a look at [Plotly](https://plot.ly/feed/)

Comment: ggplot doesn't produce javascript to make them interactive, I think you need to use another package

Comment: @nongkrong check [this](http://blog.rstudio.org/2015/06/16/shiny-0-12-interactive-plots-with-ggplot2/) out, not optimal for this question though...

Comment: @NicE that's really cool! thanks for that :)

Comment: @nongkrong good point. I guess it's only possible with javascript plots.

Comment: i realise this post is older, but the click listener could be of help (maybe it was introduced after 2015). Its not the cleanest solution, but might be of interest.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same question and found this post. I realised the question is quite old, but maybe someone is still interested in a solution.

**Challenge:**

The problem you are facing is that the ggplot will be rendered as an image: [image]

So you dont have seperate html elements you could listen on.

**Solution:**

But there is one interesting feature in ggplots in shiny. If you add a click listener to the plot, the `$x` variable of the click event is scaled to the amount of elements in the picture. So if you add an `onlick` listener the `round($click$x)` will equal the element being clicked.

See an example here:
https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/plot-interaction-advanced.html

**Reproducible example:**

I implemented a solution with textbox and highlighting, with the highlighting part coming from [Highlight a single "bar" in ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45820250/highlight-a-single-bar-in-ggplot).

Solution looks as follows:

[image]

Sample data:

```
letters <- data.frame(
  word = c("First", "Second", "Third"),
  num = c(2, 3, 4),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

The app:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(6,
           plotOutput("plot1", click = "plot1_click")
    ),
    column(5,
           uiOutput("text")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  global <- reactiveValues(toHighlight = rep(FALSE, length(letters$word)), 
    selectedBar = NULL)

  observeEvent(eventExpr = input$plot1_click, {
    global$selectedBar <- letters$word[round(input$plot1_click$x)]
    global$toHighlight <- letters$word %in% global$selectedBar
  })

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data = letters, aes(x = word, y = num, fill = ifelse(global$toHighlight, 
      yes = "yes", no = "no"))) +
      geom_bar(stat="identity") +
      scale_fill_manual(values = c("yes" = "blue", "no" = "grey" ), guide = FALSE )
  })

  output$text <- renderUI({
    req(global$selectedBar)
    textInput(inputId = "label", label = "selected text:", value = global$selectedBar)
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Good work Tonio, thank you.